# Does the Sequencer setting affect rendered OpenEXR images?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, color-management

I'm currently about to render my animations > I have set the color management settings to

Display Transform = sRGB /
View Transform = Standard /
Look = Medium High Contrast /
Exposure = 0 /
Gamma = 1 /
Sequencer = SRGB

I also added a denoiser and sharpen node in the compositing workspace.

Does the sequencer and look settings affect the final rendered open exr images? i believe openexr is suppose to be rendered out as linear? I will be compositing it in after effects.

using the latest blender version 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

No, the settings in the *Color Management* will not affect the OpenEXR images - yes, when they are displayed as render result, but not permanently in the file.

The denoising and sharpening effects however are saved in the image, also other things you add in the compositor like *Glare* etc., or if you change colors with hue, saturation etc. these changes will all be applied in the EXR. Only the colorspace is preserved.

But after saving as EXR, when you import the file for example into a new scene with different *Color Management* settings, in the *Image Editor* window they are most likely not shown by default unless you check *View as Render* in the side panel.

**Here some visual examples:**

A scene rendered with *Color Management* > *Filmic* set to *Very High Contrast* and *Exposure* at -0.5, then denoised and added *Glare* in the *Compositor* looks like this as *Render Result*:

[image: render result]

After saving it as OpenEXR (by the way, while saving there is an option *Color Management* where you can choose *Follow Scene* or *Override*, this is only relevant when saving as PNG for example, not for linear formats like EXR) you can open it in the same or a new scene, and the *Image Editor* will by default show it with *Color Space* > *Linear* and without any effect by the *Color Management*. Here I opened it in a new scene where I've set the *Color Management* > *Look* to *Low Contrast* and *Exposure* to 1, but it does not show in the *Image Editor*:

[image: exr without color management]

Only if you now enable the option *View as Render* in the sidepanel, the effect of the *Color Management* will be applied:

[image: exr viewed as render]

But notice that in all examples the image is denoised and has the glare added to the emissive part. And if you are wondering what the look is that the EXR shows when *View as Render* is disabled, it is the same as if the *Color Management* would be set to

- *View Transform* = *Standard*
- *Look* = *None*
- *Exposure* = 0.0
- *Gamma* = 1.0